# ¿Puedo enviar una tabla MySQL en JSON por medio de flask?

Tags: python, mysql, json, flask

Estoy haciendo una url que pida los productos disponibles en flask, para ello hice una función que pida la tabla y la retorne:

```
def get_mysql_connector(host):
    return mysql.connector.connect(
        host=host,
        user="...",
        password="...",
        database="...",
        charset="utf8"
    );
def gdb_products(host):
    "get db products";
    db=get_mysql_connector(host);
    send_db=db.cursor();
    send_db.execute("SELECT * FROM products WHERE disponible=1");
    p=send_db.fetchall();
    db.close();
    return p;
```

Aqui todo bien. Hace la consulta, me devuelve los productos disponible. El error esta cuando proceso la url:

```
from json import dumps as json_dumps;
@app.route("/products.json")
#No he logrado que funcione esta url:
@app.route("/products.json?<int:available>",methods=['GET'])
def get_products(available=1):
    return Response(json_dumps(query.gdb_products(production)), mimetype='application/json');
```

El error ocurre cuando intento formatear a JSON antes de enviarlo. Este error me da:

```
 File "C:\Users\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2213, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2193, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "C:\Users\users\projects\productos\server.py", line 35, in get_products
    return Response(json_dumps(query.gdb_products(production)), mimetype='application/json');
  File "C:\Users\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable
```

¿Hay una forma de enviar el resultado MySQL por medio de una petición HTTP con flask?

Comment: El error es claro: un valor de tu base de datos tiene un tipo (*decimal*) que tu serializador de JSON no puede convertir a un tipo de dato JSON válido. Tendrás que hacer la conversión manual o usar un serializador especializado en tipos de de MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El módulo *json* de la *stdlib* no soporta la serialización de objetos `decimal.Decimal`, tipo que parece ser retornado por algún campo de tu base de datos. Tienes varias opciones:

### Usar `flask.json`

Esta opción seria la mas apropiada para tu caso, el resto van más enfocadas a casos en los que no se use Flask y tengan el mismo problema.

Flask provee de soporte para ello directamente mediante el paquete [`flask.json`](https://pydocbrowser.github.io/flask/latest/flask.json.html). Desde la versión 2.0.2 tanto `jsonify`, como `dump`/`dumps` soportan la serialización de objetos `Decimal`.

Un ejemplo mínimo reproducible:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/productos')
def obtener_productos():
    productos = {'pan': Decimal(1.23), 'arroz': Decimal(2.32)}
    return jsonify(productos)
```

### Usar json de la stdlib y extender JSONEncoder

En la [documentación del módulo json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) tienes un ejemplo de este procedimiento pero con `complex` en vez de `Decimal`.

```
import decimal
import json


class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, decimal.Decimal):
            return str(obj)
        return super().default(obj)


productos = {'pan': Decimal(1.23), 'arroz': Decimal(2.32)}
productos_json = json.dumps(productos, cls=DecimalEncoder)
print(productos_json)
```

### Usar paquetes externos

Hay paquetes de terceros que si permiten serializar objetos `Decimal` por defecto, por ejemplo:

- [ujson](https://github.com/ultrajson/ultrajson) (ultrajson)
- [simplejson](https://pypi.org/project/simplejson/)

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Mi humilde comentario trataba de guiar al AP a este tipo de alternativas. +1 para ti.